# Show fragment when click ActionBar menu return null

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I want to show/hide fragment when i click the action bar menu item. But my app give me error when i click. Fragment coming on first run. When I want to hide fragment App give null error.

How can i solve this problem ?

Thanks in now.

**Logcat**

```
01-26 03:48:40.942    2295-2295/test.sy.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:661)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**LayerList.Java**

```
package test.sy.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class LayerList extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layerlist,container,false);
    return mView;

}
}
```

**MainActivity.Java**

```
package test.sy.myapplication;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}




@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        case R.id.showsth:

            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in,
                    android.R.animator.fade_out);
            ft.show(fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment));
            ft.commit();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix this issue.

This situation caused by adding fragment without any framelayout.

Once add framelayout to main activity. And give it id;

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="450dp"

    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"></FrameLayout>
```

Second;

Create fragment with its activty. In this example our fragment name may be FragmentTest.java and our Fragments activity  may be fragment_activity.xml.

And adding fragment to main activiy;
In Oncreate method you should add this line;

```
FragmentTest Mfragmenttest = new FragmentTest();
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
//R.id.frameLayout is our frame layouts id. 
 ft.add(R.id.frameLayout, Mfragmenttest , "Hello Fragment");
ft.commit
```

Answer (score 0):

`ft.show(fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment));`

this line causes the problem

`fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment)` returns null.

With this line you are trying to find a fragment in `layout/activity_main` which is previously added to `R.id.fragment`.
If you didn't add or replace fragment before, it is obvious to return null AMK